# Chrome creates duplicate slave windows on refresh

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm migrating my chrome extension from manifest v2 to v3 and I faced a problem which was:

When I create a slave window of my webpage, it works great, but if refresh the page, chrome creates the same slave window (as it's supposed) and a duplicate of a slave window.

before migration I handled it with **setSelfAsOpener** flag in window.create, but now for some reason Im getting an error, which says: ***Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot specify setSelfAsOpener Service Worker extension.***

any suggestions how to fix it ?

```
   chrome.windows.create({
     type: 'popup',
     incognito: true,
     url: 'some url',
     setSelfAsOpener: true
     }, (wnd) => {
       console.log(wnd)   // returns undefined and throws
     }                    // error mentioned above
    )
```

and without flag it duplicates...

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Im afraid Im not allowed to provide a reproductable example, but I can provide a flow of what I did:

Comment: I edied description

Comment: You're code doesn't work, because a) It contains semicolons `;` where there should be commas `,` and b) It contains equals signs `=` where there should be colons `:`

Comment: "**minimal**, reproducible example" means a simple test extension that demonstrates the problem, not all of your code. Creating a simple test extension also allows you to check if your code actually works.

Comment: I didn't consider syntax while editing the post, in code everything is ok, I mean there is no syntax issues

Comment: I googled the error message, and the only place Google found it is in the Chromium source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_api.cc --- I don't know if the comments around the error message mean that service workers will never be able to use `setSelfAsOpener: true`, or if something needs still to be implemented in Chrome before this will work.

Comment: You'll have to use a completely different solution e.g. check the existence of the window before creating it.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thank you mate, doesn't solved my problem of course, but at least I know now, that it's not caused because of my code :D

Comment: @wOxxOm Ye I was considering this scenario, but hoped that it was my mistake, and that setSelfIsopener will work, after I fix it, but apparently it won't work in service workers :(